# Automatically executing code in browser console on key press (firefox)

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have a little snippet of code that I want to execute in the console: `:screenshot --selector canvas.page` to make a screenshot of a specific canvas on a page. Now i was wondering if i can execute that in console when I press specific keys in Firefox. I don't know how I can accomplish that and am hoping for some help.

Comment: Welcome to the community @yohlozdxrcicimeixj. You may want to add in some more specific details and to check out a post on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You want to capture the `keyCode` that was entered and react to the code(s) you are looking for. Look at this link and update your question with specifics about the issues you are having implementing => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Comment: Can you click the Run button or press Ctrl + Enter? Or, type the ! character and the name of the snippet?