# How to periodically/ on key press execute js code in the browser console of firefox without having to open it?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I want to periodically or on a specific key press execute the following in the console of Firefox: `:screenshot --selector canvas.page` whereas the actual code is not that important, it's more about the implementation of executing in the console without having to change to it every time and execute it.

Comment: `setInterval()` ?

Comment: I tried that already but that doesn't really do what I want and i still need to open the console for it

Comment: Is this maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/65359612/4415884?

Answer (score 0):

```
let period = 5000; //each 5s
setInterval(() => {
  console.log(":screenshot --selector canvas.page");
}, period);
```

or by key press

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', evt => {
    if(evt.key == "Enter") console.log(":screenshot --selector canvas.page") //on Enter Key pressed
});
```

Comment: do i have to embed in the page or is there a way of using it on any page?

Comment: and it doesn't work i think because it doesn't take console.log(:screenshot) nor just :screenshot

Comment: You need to embed in your page, in your HTML code within the script tag, or in separate *.js file and link that file in your page.